how to verify that all primary keys appears in two tables - one of the table contains a foreign key to the other
For example - suppose that I have two tables: Humans and Animals.
"Humans" table looks like this: id, name, age etc.
"animals" table looks like this: id, name, (foreign key) human_id, etc.
Need to suppose that there is exact one match between the humans and the animals.
Now I want to write a query that validate in one query that each human has an animal and each animal has human owner.
If for example one human exist in the humans table, but it does not have a match in the animals the query need return it in someway, on the other hand if there is an animal which exist in the animals table, but doesn't has a foreign key match to the humans the query need to raise an issue in some way.
I prefer that both validation will be in one single query.
I tried to do an left join between the humans and the animals, but it doesn't cover the case where an animal exist, but it doesn't has a foreign key in the humans table

Please review [mre] and update the post with table DDL and example data to cover each of the test cases you've described. Also add the failed query you tried. Make it as easy as practical for others to replicate the problem. As to the problem you've described, use a FULL OUTER JOIN and in the WHERE clause select rows where either table's id IS NULL.

If animals.human_id has both a NOT NULL and foreign key constraint, then the database will ensure that every animal belongs to a human and there will be no need for a query to test the condition.

Agree, but this happens in a perfect world. In a perfect world everything is possible. Now I want to look at this problem from the QA tester side where all the possible mistakes can happen and I need to validate them somehow
So the question is not how to prevent this, but how to identify this situation

@JohnH thanks that is exactly what I looked for. Full Outer Join

QA testing should verify that the undesired state can't occur, not that it hasn't occurred. The proper way to do this is to attempt to insert data that violates the requirement and observe that an appropriate exception is raised. Querying for data that violates requirements is useful for identifying bad data in a broken application but does not demonstrate correct behavior; however, the presence of such data does confirm that the implementation is defective.

You can find missing partners with NOT EXISTS:
SELECT animal.id, animal.name
FROM animals
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM humans
                  WHERE animals.human_id = humans.id);

In a similar fashion, you can find humans without animal.
An alternative is a full outer join:
SELECT humans.id, humans.name,
       animals.id, animals.name
FROM humans
   FULL JOIN animals ON animals.human_id = humans.id
WHERE animals.id IS NULL
   OR humans.id IS NULL;

You can prevent the problem from happening by defining a foreign key from humans to animals as well. Define the foreign keys as NOT NULL and DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, so that the check for the circular dependency is deferred to the end of the transaction.

I don't have access to the creation and manipulation of the DB I want to look at it from the QA view side.
I could do it with two left join, but looked for a way to do it on one single query

@Hodiya Eyal That looks like you want a full [outer] join, then, and check for nullness in either id column. Your should get a database and post at least some table definitions. If you want to insist on a one-to-one mapping, the simplest solution might be to use only one table, and a non-null animal column, e.g. in a table called 'humans'.
